# Difference Between Command and Adapter Patterns

Tags: design-patterns

In Adapter pattern we change the interface of an object to another one to use it from another interface.

In Command pattern we change the interface of an object to a common Command interface, providing an execute method that calls the real methods which does the job. Isn't this exactly the same thing which adapter pattern already does? What's the point of Command pattern then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Command` design pattern is used to solve problems like:
*- How can an object be configured (customized) with a request?

- And how can the request be (ex)changed dynamically at run-time?*

The point of `Command` is to decouple a request from its invoker
and encapsulate it in a separate object (Command interface).
Invoker then delegates a request to a command object dynamically.

The `Adapter` design pattern (object adapter) is used to solve problems like:
*- How can an object be accessed that has an incompatible interface

without changing existing interfaces?*

The point of `Adapter` is to work through a separate object 
that adapts an incompatible interface, i.e., that implements our needed
interface (Target) in terms of (by delegating to) the incompatible interface.

The `Command` pattern is more similar to the `Strategy` pattern,
which decouples an algorithm from its context and encapsulates it 
in a separate object (Strategy).

For further discussion see the GoF Design Patterns Memory for learning
object-oriented design & programming 
at http://w3sdesign.com.

Comment: Can we say the two patterns have the same implementation but different aims ?

Comment: Maybe the implementation of the Adapter (object adapter) is somewhat easier:

The Adapter pattern implements an **existing** interface (Target).
Clients refer to this interface and needn't to be changed.

The Command pattern defines a **new** interface (Command) and implements different requests.
Clients must be designed/implemented/changed so that they
delegate a request to one of different command objects.